# How to make git ask for password

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm using bitbucket and has entered my password once and now I keep getting the follwoing error

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://username@bitbucket.org/repo/smodels.git/': The requested URL returned error: 403
```

How can I make it ask for my password again?

Comment: What client and operating system?

Comment: windows machine and git client

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove credentials from Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git)